# Join two different query results Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, multiple-tables

I'll start by showing you my relations:

```
class Users
  has_many :user_semester_courses
  has_many :registered_courses, through: :user_semester_courses, class_name: 'SemesterCourse', foreign_key: 'semester_course_id', source: :semester_course
end

class SemesterCourses
  belongs_to :semester
end

class UserSemesterCourse
  belongs_to :semester_course
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to basically have the `user_semester_courses` sorted by semesters.

From my understanding, I need to:

1. Join the `user.registered_courses` (which are SemesterCourses) with `semesters` and sort them by semester
2. Join the result with `user_semester_courses`

I tried a lot of joins and I can't seem to achieve my desired result.

Comment: Do you have a model called UserSemesterCourse?  And is there a particular semester column you want to sort on, or are you just sorting by id?  If it's by semester id, then you don't need to join the semesters, you can just sort by semester_courses.semester_id

Comment: Yes I have a model called `UserSemesterCourse` and yes each `Semester` has a `term` and a `year` which I want to sort on. I have implemented comparison operators in the `Semester` model if that might help.

Comment: Please check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Data in the `Semester` table isn't sorted by `id`. For example: Semester where id = 1 has a year of 2015 where Semester where id = 5 has year of 2014